# How to set the `auto-mode-alist` for `*.el` files when installing packages

Tags: package

I like to have my `auto-mode-alist` for `*.el` files set up to open them in a custom major-mode that is `buffer-read-only`.  When installing certain packages through the choices available when typing `M-x list-packages`, the package process creates an `...autoloads.el` file.  Adding information to that `...autoloads.el` file during the package building process fails because the buffer is read only.

Essentially, I'd like the `auto-mode-alist` to temporarily be set to `nil` so that the process of creating the `...autoloads.el` file is working in a `fundamental-mode` buffer instead of my custom major-mode.

Some suggestions on how to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add a second entry to `auto-mode-alist` for these autoload files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'package
  (defadvice package-generate-autoloads
    (around disable-custom-major-mode activate preactivate compile)
    (let ((auto-mode-alist nil))
      ad-do-it)))
```

I haven't tested if it works, but I'm pretty sure it does what you ask.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed do the job -- thank you very much!